# Rails: How to set port number for the asset hosts in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline

Rails lets me set multiple asset hosts as an application configuration. Problem is, I've been writing the full host as an argument. That is, in development I've been appending the ":3000" to it. Which has worked fine, until the day I had to run 2 projects in parallel, and one of them add to go to a different port (let's say, 3001). As I already read, Rails app can't possibly know which port the web server is listening to. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can use [asset_path](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html) helper instead of the full path by hand, and put different asset_hosts in `production.rb` and `development.rb`.

For the port issue, inside a controller method you can get it from the request, but, outside, I don't know a way to do that... you can try the `PORT` enviroment variable.

Hope it helps.

Comment: that's exactly my issue... I'm setting the development hosts in development.rb and setting the PORT through a variable, like you just said... but I just can't know in advance if the web server is listening to that port. And that is what I want to know.